# Hitting endpoint GET of HTTP REST API, shows "Invalid User"

Tags: json, rest, api, amazon-web-services

I am hitting endpoint GET of HTTP REST API, http://tw-http-hunt-api-1062625224.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/challenge

It says "For every API call, pass your UserID as an HTTP header with key 'userId'."

So I am doing http://tw-http-hunt-api-1062625224.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/challenge/userId/xxxx

But it shows:[Invalid User!]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the userId in HTTP headers, not in path. Below is the CURL equivalent:

```
curl -X GET http://tw-http-hunt-api-1062625224.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/challenge -H 'userId: test'
```

You need to send similar request from your client.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty Simple,

You need to pass HTTP Header with the key as "userId" and value as "WHATEVER_USERNAME_YOU_ARE_GIVEN"

[NOTE: I'm sharing in the context of a Java Code]

Something like this,

```
private static HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(USER_ID_HEADER, USER_ID);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return headers;
}
```

Here,
**USER_ID_HEADER = "userId"** and
**USER_ID = "USERNAME_I_WISH_TO_PASS"**

Please let me know if you still struggle finding the solution.